# How do I specify the CodeUri in my pipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

I'm doing a serverless app in lambda using CloudFormation.

In my CodeBuild project, I set it to zip up the output and place it in "myBucket\AWSServerless1.zip" and it does correctly.

Now I'm working on my CodePipeline, I reference the original CodeBuild project. However, now instead, it puts it in codepipeline-us-west-#####. That's fine. The issue is that the .zip file has a RANDOM name. CodePipeline ignores the name I gave it in the CodeBuild project.

In the serverless.template, I have to specify the CodeUri (which seems to be the CodeBuild project output for some odd reason). If I reference the AWSServerless1.zip, it works fine (but its not building to there, so its stale code)... but...

Since CodePipeline calling CodeBuild gives it a random name, how am I supposed to reference the ACTUAL BuildArtifact in the serverless.template?

Comment: I had a similar experience. Please remove the code URI in the template.yaml and try. I was able to get it working that way.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very weird, I was stuck with this behavior of CodePipeline and then had to rewrite the buildspec to make CodePipeline work. CodePipeline makes it's own zip file even if you create your own zip through CodeBuild as well and that too with a unique name.

But there is one way out, Codepipeline will create one zip file but it will unzip it while giving the artifact to CodeDeploy. So you need not worry about its name. CodeDeploy will get the unzipped version of your code. CodePipeline keeps track of the name and it will always point to the newest one.

Suppose :

CodePipeline creates artifact : `some-random-name.zip`

```
some-random-name
       |- deploy/lib/lambda-code
       |- some-file.yaml
```

Whenever CodePipeline gives artifact to CodeDeploy, it will unzip it so you can anytime refer the code under `some-random-name.zip`

So in your case when you give CodeUri in the SAM template just give the folder name which is `deploy` where your lambda code is present.

```
Resources:
  Hello:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: example.MyHandler
      Runtime: java8
      CodeUri: deploy
      Description: ''
      MemorySize: 512
      Timeout: 15
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm using .NET Core and serverless.template. I tried putting various stuff in there, but it seems like its required to be an S3 URL to a zip. I kind of got around it by the deploy stage having 2 parts, 1) deploy to the S3 container to overwrite the fixed name zip 2) now do the cloudformation deploy

Comment: If I try to put something in the serverless.template like "." it errors out saying it MUST be s3://... ugh... even with the workaround, now I've run into the situation where they don't let you update cloudformation stacks. Wth? Why would you not be allowed to redeploy code? I dunno… AWS is AWFUL in my opinion. 3 weeks so far trying to get this running. Everything breaks or fails so easily with non sensical errors. I literally got up and running in CI/CD in Azure in 2 hrs with 0 experience in both. AWS 3 weeks and counting :(.

Comment: But anyways :)… with serverless.template is there a way to reference the build artifact cleaning without deploying to the S3 first?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error and I managed to work around it by doing the following:

1- On the build specification (**buildspec.yml**) add a sam package command (this generates a **package.yml** that will be used by cloudformation to deploy the lambda).

```
build:
  commands:
    - sam package
      --template-file ../template.yaml
      --output-template-file ../package.yml
      --s3-bucket onnera-ci-cd-bucketcode here
```

2- Add the **package.yml** to output artifacts

```
artifacts:
  files:
    - DeviceProvisioning/package.yml
```

3- On the **template.yaml** that will be deployed reference directly the CodeUri (internally this will be resolved to the bucket with the output artificats from codebuild).

```
Resources:
  DeviceProvisioningFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function 
    Properties:
      CodeUri: DeviceProvisioningFunction/target/DeviceProvisioningFunction-1.0.jar
```

4- On the pipeline make the output of the build phase avaialble on deployment phase:

```
const buildOutput = [new codepipeline.Artifact()];
const buildAction = new codepipeline_actions.CodeBuildAction({
  actionName: 'CodeBuild',
  project: deviceProvisioning,
  input: sourceOutput,
  outputs: buildOutput, 
});
```

5- Use the build output to specify the templatePath on the deploy action:

```
const deployAction = new codepipeline_actions.CloudFormationCreateUpdateStackAction({
  extraInputs: buildAction.actionProperties.outputs,
  actionName: "UpdateLambda",
  stackName: "DeviceProvisioningStack",
  adminPermissions: true,
  templatePath: buildOutput[0].atPath("package.yml"),
  cfnCapabilities: [CfnCapabilities.AUTO_EXPAND, CfnCapabilities.NAMED_IAM]
});
```

Make sure that the output artifacts from the build phase are available on the deploy phase.

[image]